# How to set up a dependency which depends on a element from another module in hilt

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have a module like so:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class) // scope - ViewModel
object ViewModelsComponents {

 
    @Provides
    @ViewModelScoped
    fun provideMyRepo() =  MyRepo() /*<- database from another 
        module 
        needs to be 
        passed here*/

}
```

my repo class

```
class MyRepo @Injected constructor(private val db: RoomDbClass){
......
}
```

I followed the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-multi-module) and followed the three steps

1. The entrypoint interface

   @EntryPoint
   @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
   interface DbDependency {

   ```
     fun provideDatabase () = RoomDbClass().instance
   }
   ```

2.Dagger Component

```
@Component(dependencies = [DbDependency ::class])
interface DBComponent {

  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {
    fun context(@BindsInstance context: Context): Builder
    fun appDependencies(dbDependencies: DbDependency): Builder
    fun build(): DBComponent
  }
}
```

the doc shows how to inject the component in an activity which is
not what I am looking for.

How do I pass the dagger component to my repo module ??

Comment: Are you trying to inject it in a class which isn't to @HiltEntryPoint - hence the @EntryPoint?

Comment: I am new to hilt so I am not sure what you are asking, I am just trying to use the dependency in a non hilt module like the documentation says but in the object where the modules are defined not in an activity like the documentaion says